# Find out username of the current user in Windows in Haskell?

Tags: windows, haskell

I hope I have not missed an obvious answer to this somewhere, but in case I have - I apologise.

`System.Posix.User` feature a `getLoginName` for finding the login name of the currently logged in user. Now, what would work for getting the same information on the Windows platforms?

Comment: Haven't tested, does this [work](http://lpaste.net/111112) ?

Comment: @Sibi `USERNAME` gives you the user name, but you may want to query `USERDOMAIN` and/or `USERDNSDOMAIN` as well... (Might vary by OS version, I'm not sure.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Thanks for confirming. :) How does [USERDOMAIN](http://environmentvariables.org/UserDomain) help since it seems to contain the name of the domain ?

Comment: @Sibi I'm just saying that if the OP wants the _fully qualified_ name (i.e., enough information to uniquely determine which user account), the domain name may be required. (Or not. It depends why you want to know.)

Comment: `USERDOMAIN` will certainly be of use to me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [USERNAME](http://environmentvariables.org/UserName) environment variable contains the name of the user currently logged on in a windows system, you can use that to find out the username:

```
import System.Environment

main = getEnv "USERNAME" >>= print
```